# Cannot search specific text using pdfquery

Tags: python, pdf

I am trying to scrape data from a pdf table based on the question number in a list. However, when I use LTTextBoxHorizontal:contains it returns the question at 1.30 and not 1.3, because 1.30 comes first in the xml. How do I narrow down to search exactly what is in the list?

```
def search_terms():
    for q in questions:
        answer =  pdf.pq('LTTextBoxHorizontal:contains("{}")'.format(q))[0]            
        x0 = float(answer.get("x0",0)) + 350
        y0 = float(answer.get("y0",0)) 
        x1 = float(answer.get("x1",0)) + 480
        y1 = float(answer.get("y1",0)) 
        answer = (x0, y0, x1, y1)
        locations.append(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `contains()`:

```
def search_terms():
    for q in questions:
        answer = pdf.pq('LTTextBoxHorizontal:containsExact("{}")'.format(q))[0]
        x0 = float(answer.get("x0", 0)) + 350
        y0 = float(answer.get("y0", 0))
        x1 = float(answer.get("x1", 0)) + 480
        y1 = float(answer.get("y1", 0))
        answer = (x0, y0, x1, y1)
        locations.append(answer)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I tried containsExact but it return "The pseudo-class :constainsexact() is unknown".